# Image Histogram Implementation with Metal on macOS

Tags: macos, histogram, metal, thread-synchronization

I am aware of MPSImageHistogram, but I'd like to implement the algorithm myself to understand Metal better. However, I run into thread synchronization problem when trying to accumulate pixel information into histogram bins, and I got no clue how to solve it. On iOS, I think I have a couple of considerable options including programmable blending and thread group sharing. Unfortunately, those are not available on macOS.

I appreciate any general tip/direction to approach the problem on macOS, either thread synchronization or image histogram.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest approach is probably to use atomic variables (e.g. `atomic_uint`) and atomic operations (e.g. `atomic_fetch_add_explicit()`) to increment the counts. You may get a lot of contention which may cause performance issues, but that's sort of another question.

Comment: @KenThomasese I thought of atomic variables, but I don't think I can create an array of `atomic_uint` to manage all of histogram bins. That would be a lot of counter input arguments to pass into the shaders.

Comment: Yes, you can treat a buffer as an array of `atomic_uint`. `device atomic_uint* bins[[buffer(0)]]` and then pass `&bins[i]` into one of the atomic functions.

Comment: I didn't think that would work at all. I am going to test it out. Thanks a lot @ken.